# PHP - Convert RGB values to CMYK percentages

Tags: php

I am getting RGB Values using this php code

```
<?php
$im = imagecreatefrompng("img/t4.png");
$rgb = imagecolorat($im, 15, 15);
$r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
$g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
$b = $rgb & 0xFF;
?>
```

And i need CMYK percentages also

Can someone please give me som guide lines.

Thanks.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858131/rgb-to-cmyk-and-back-algorithm

Answer (score 2):

```
<?
function hex2rgb($hex) {
  $color = str_replace('#','',$hex);
  $rgb = array('r' => hexdec(substr($color,0,2)),
               'g' => hexdec(substr($color,2,2)),
               'b' => hexdec(substr($color,4,2)));
  return $rgb;
}

function rgb2cmyk($var1,$g=0,$b=0) {
   if(is_array($var1)) {
      $r = $var1['r'];
      $g = $var1['g'];
      $b = $var1['b'];
   }
   else $r=$var1;
   $cyan    = 255 - $r;
   $magenta = 255 - $g;
   $yellow  = 255 - $b;
   $black   = min($cyan, $magenta, $yellow);
   $cyan    = @(($cyan    - $black) / (255 - $black)) * 255;
   $magenta = @(($magenta - $black) / (255 - $black)) * 255;
   $yellow  = @(($yellow  - $black) / (255 - $black)) * 255;
   return array('c' => $cyan / 255,
                'm' => $magenta / 255,
                'y' => $yellow / 255,
                'k' => $black / 255);
}

$color=rgb2cmyk(hex2rgb('#FF0000')); 
pdf_setcolor($pdf, "both", "cmyk", $color['c'], $color['m'], $color['y'], $color['k']);
?>
```

Comment: This is a good answer! The fine detail about this is, that this function already performs UCR ("under color removal") which replaces equal shares of color with black. This generally leads to more "neutral" colors, especially grey tones often lose their color tint this way.