# Android: How to convert CMYK color space file to RGB?

Tags: java, android, rgb, cmyk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [RGB to CMYK and back algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858131/rgb-to-cmyk-and-back-algorithm)

As far as I know Android doesn't support files with CMYK color space. But my application has to show such files. So, how to convert CMYK color space file to RGB?

Comment: This has been asked [several times before](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=[java]%20%2bcmyk%20%2brgb).

Comment: Yes, I saw these questions, but there is no proper description how to do it in the Android project

Comment: Why do you think that being on Android would have any relevance to the CYMK->RGB algorithm? You should be able to adapt any of the Java answers to your project. If you cannot, please ask a more specific question after you have tried.

Comment: Lack of AWT on Android is a major barrier to any of the previous questions that are Java answers working on Android