# CMYK Barcodes with zxing

Tags: java, rgb, cmyk

I want to print a bunch of Barcodes in a printery and they told me, that my Barcodes (Code128 and QR-Code) are not in the correct color space. They are in RGB, but I need CMYK.
What can I do to convert those images into CMYK images?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: check this answer, it should help you: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858131/rgb-to-cmyk-and-back-algorithm)