# How to extract CMYK color values from a image (tiff) data byte array

Tags: java, image, colors, tiff, cmyk

Basically I need to extract CMYK color values from a byte array containing image data (tif image). I am not interested in converting the values to rgb colorspase. I just need to extract the cyan, magenta, yellow, and key (black) values (ideally in hex but beggars can not by choosers). Can libraries like JAI or imageIO help me do that?

Edit : In line with the comments I received  I tried the following

```
   Raster r = renderedImage.getData();
   ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
           for(int i =0; i<r.getWidth();i++ ){
               for(int j = 0; j<r.getHeight();j++){
                  baos.write((byte)r.getSample(i,j,0));
               }
           }
       byte [] cyanBand = baos.toByteArray();
```

However, the resulting values in the array do not look correct. I am following the correct approach?

Any ideas would be more than welcomed .

Thanks in advance

Comment: Related question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858131/rgb-to-cmyk-and-back-algorithm

Comment: @Gilbert Le Blanc In order to get the CMYK values I want, is converting from rgb the only/easiest option?

Comment: Yes, it's the only option.

Comment: For clarification: your input image *is* in RGB? TIFF images usually only store the data in one color space.

Comment: @Jongware The input image colorspace is CMYK. I just do not know how to extract the four color values/arrays

Comment: Ah, so you don't have to do the conversion yourself. Then you only need to access the raw image data, and I suppose either of the libraries you mention can give you that. Reading raw TIFF data is well documented, but there are *lots* of data variants. A good library shields you from all the gritty low level details.

Comment: Yes, `ImageIO` can help you read the data in its original layout (use `ImageReader.readRaster()`). If the image data is CMYK, you will be able to access the CMYK data. ImageIO will not read TIFF by default. You will need a TIFF plugin, either jai-imageio or another 3rd party plugin.